# Why does centering/standardizing the regressor make the p value for the intercept zero?

Tags: regression, p-value

I've noticed that when standardizing or centering the regressor(s), the p value for the intercept becomes smaller. Does this always happen? If so, why?

I know that
$$
var(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1} 
$$

and that the t-stat is

$$
t_i = \frac{\hat{\beta}_i}{SE(\hat{\beta}_i)}
$$

I can't tell from this general equation, nor the ones for simple linear regression found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression why the $t_i$ will increase and thus result in a reduction in the p-value.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/regression-proof-that-the-point-of-averages-x-y-lies-on-the-estimated-regressi offers a strong hint.

Answer (score 1):

When you center the predictors, the only coefficient that changes is the intercept. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/518969/60613).

Particularly of notice, is the fact that

> \begin{matrix}
> \hat{\beta_L} =
> \left[\matrix{n^{-1}\mathbf {1}_n^T \\
> (X^{*T}CX^*)^{-1}X^{*T}C}\right]y
> &
> \hat{\beta_X} =
> \left[\matrix{
> n^{-1}\mathbf {1}_n^T+n^{-1} (\mathbf {1}_n^TX^*(X^{*T}CX^*)^{-1}X^{*T})C
> \\
> (X^{*T}CX^*)^{-1}X^{*T}C
> }\right]y
> \end{matrix}

It's not particularly obvious that the p-value will diminish, it can actually increase.
But, for non-trivial transformation of the independent variables, it's almost guaranteed to change.

Comment: I'll check out your derivation in the linked post in a little bit, but I just want to follow up on "it can actually increase." When can it increase?

Comment: Suppose that the estimated intercept for the centered model is exactly zero (there exist values of the means and variances of x and y for which this will be true). Then the centered p-value is 1, regardless of the standard deviation ...