# The OLS prediction is different after standardizing the data

Tags: regression, data-visualization, linear

I have a dataset where $X\in N\times1$ is the carats and $y\in N\times 1$ is the diamond price in USD.

I modelled the data using $$
y\sim\mathcal N(Xw,\sigma)
$$I removed the bias from the model so that at $x=0$, the price would be also $0$.

Now, I standardized the data by computing$$
\hat X=\frac{X-\hat\mu}{\hat\sigma}
$$before I use auto differentiation to minimize the negative log probability of the gaussian distribution with mean $Xw$.

---

Now I am plotting the results for the prediction.

I computed $\hat y=\hat X w$ (instead of $X$) and plotted the coordinates $(X, \hat y)$. **This gives me a different result than without standardizing the data at all.**

Am I plotting it correctly? To predict $X$, I have to use $\hat y =\hat X w$ since I standardized the features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The regression coefficient ("weight") between standardized variables is just the correlation coefficient. In turn, the regression coefficient between unstandardized variables is the correlation times the ratio of the standard deviations.**

I'm going to use slightly different notation to explain. You have
$$
 y_{i} = b_{0} + b_{1} x_{i}
$$
Rewrite with $b_{0} = \bar{y} - b_{1}\bar{x}$, where $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are the means of $x$ and $y$, respectively, to get
$$
 y_{i} = \bar{y} - b_{1} \bar{x} + b_{1} x_{i}
$$
which simplifies to
$$
 y_{i} - \bar{y} = b_{1}(x_{i} - \bar{x})
$$
Now recall that the OLS estimator of $b_{1} = \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i} - \bar{x})(y_{i}-\bar{y})}{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}} = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(x,y)}{\operatorname{Var}(x)}$. Now define the standard deviation $s_{x} = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(x)}$, and multiply and divide the expression for the OLS estimator by $s_{y} = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(y)}$, to get
$$
 b_{1} = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(x,y)}{s_{x}s_{y}} \frac{s_{y}}{s_{x}} = r_{xy} \frac{s_{y}}{s_{x}}
$$
where $r_{xy}$ is the correlation coefficient between $x$ and $y$. Take this expression for $b_{1}$ and plug it into the equation right above to get
$$
y_{i} - \bar{y} = r_{xy} \frac{s_{y}}{s_{x}} (x_{i} - \bar{x})
$$
Now divide both sides by $s_{y}$ and move $s_{x}$ into the parenthesis, to arrive at
$$
 \frac{y_{i} - \bar{y}}{s_{y}} = r_{xy} \left( \frac{x_{i} - \bar{x}}{s_{x}} \right)
$$
Obviously, $\frac{x_{i} - \bar{x}}{s_{x}}$ and $\frac{y_{i} - \bar{y}}{s_{y}}$ are the standardized versions ("z-scores") of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Long story short: $b_{1} \neq r_{xy}$, but $b_{1} = r_{xy} \cdot \frac{s_{y}}{s_{x}}$.

Let's verify in R in using [ggplot2's diamond data](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/diamonds.html).

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
```

The unstandardized regression gives

```
coef(lm(price ~ carat, data=diamonds))
(Intercept)       carat 
  -2256.361    7756.426
```

while the standardized regression gives

```
coef(lm(scale(price) ~ scale(carat), data=diamonds))
(Intercept)     scale(carat) 
1.355088e-14    9.215913e-01
```

where the intercept is practically zero ([as one should expect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/518929)) while the regression coefficient is simply the correlation coefficient.

```
with(diamonds, cor(price, carat))
[1] 0.9215913
```

And, of course

```
with(diamonds, cor(price, carat)*sd(price)/sd(carat))
[1] 7756.426
```

gives the original OLS estimate for the unstandardized variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if $y_i$ is not scaled and the model takes intercept to be zero. And I standardized $x$, from your answer, will the standardized regression now have an intercept?

Comment: If you standadize $x$ but not $y$, your regression still needs an intercept because $\bar{y}$ won't be zero.